# Объяните работу программы

Tags: java

Учу java.Наткнулся на пример в книге по поиску простых чисел до n числа и что-то не могу понять как она работает.Объясните пожалуйста принцип работы программы

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = scanner.nextInt();
    boolean b = true;
    for (int c = 2; c <= a; c++) {
      for (int i = 2; i < c; i++) {
        if (c % i == 0) {
          b = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (b) System.out.println(c);
      else b = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем случае, как я понимаю, `a` это `n`.
Для всех чисел от `2` до `n`:

```
for (int c = 2; c <= a; c++) {
```

Проверяем, делится ли оно на одно из чисел из диапазона от `2` до `n - 1`

```
  for (int i = 2; i < c; i++) {
    if (c % i == 0) {
```

Если да, то число непростое (по определению).
В этом случае выходим из вложенного цикла:

```
  b = false;
  break;
```

В случае если b осталось равным true - число простое, печатаем его и выставляем флаг в исходное значение:

```
if (b) System.out.println(c);
```

Далее переходим к проверке следующего числа.

Comment: Добавлю, что алгоритм плохой и на его примере хорошо объяснять, как не надо делать.

Comment: не могли бы более подробно объяснить эти строки 

      for (int c = 2; c <= a; c++) {
      for (int i = 2; i < c; i++) {
        if (c % i == 0) {